# ERC721 testing transferFrom()

Tags: erc-721, truffle-test, transferfrom

How can I test (truffle test or development console) the following:

```
await nft.transferFrom(accounts[0], accounts[1], 1); 
await nft.transferFrom(accounts[1], accounts[0],1);
```

The second line throws

```
ERC721: transfer caller is not owner nor approved
```

If I change to

```
await nft.transferFrom(accounts[1], accounts[0],1,{from: accounts[1]});
```

the following exception is thrown:

```
Ownable: caller is not the owner
```

How can I test a transfer from another account then `accounts[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truffle supports optional parameters for all calls. You can see them at least here (even if this is for the default parameters, it's valid for any call): https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/tree/master/packages/contract#mycontractdefaultsnew_defaults

So you can just an extra parameter `from`, like this: `await nft.transferFrom(accounts[0], accounts[1], 1, { from: accounts[1] });`

Comment: Thank you very much @Lauri  for your answer. If I use `await nft.transferFrom(accounts[1], accounts[0],1,{from: accounts[1]});`I get `Ownable: caller is not the owner`. Please see in my question above.

Comment: Sorry. Your solution works perfect! Thank you very much, Lauri!